# Unable to trigger composer/airflow dag from Cloud function that triggers when there are changes in cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth, google-cloud-composer

I have created and ran dags on a `google-cloud-composer` environment (**dlkpipelinesv1** : composer-1.13.0-airflow-1.10.12). I am able to trigger these dags manually, and using the scheduler, but I am stuck when it comes to triggering them via `cloud-functions` that detect changes in a `google-cloud-storage` bucket.

Note that I had another GC-Composer environment (**pipelines**:composer-1.7.5-airflow-1.10.2) that used those same google cloud functions to trigger the relevant dags, and **it was working**.

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) to create the functions that trigger the dags. So I retrieved the following variables:

```
PROJECT_ID = <project_id>
CLIENT_ID = <client_id_retrieved_by_running_the_code_in_the_guide_within_my_gcp_console>
WEBSERVER_ID = <airflow_webserver_id>
DAG_NAME = <dag_to_trigger>
WEBSERVER_URL = f"https://{WEBSERVER_ID}.appspot.com/api/experimental/dags/{DAG_NAME}/dag_runs"


def file_listener(event, context):
    """Entry point of the cloud function: Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    logging.info("Running the file listener process")
    logging.info(f"event : {event}")
    logging.info(f"context : {context}")
    file = event
    if file["size"] == "0" or "DTM_DATALAKE_AUDIT_COMPTAGE" not in file["name"] or ".filepart" in file["name"].lower():
        logging.info("no matching file")
        exit(0)

    logging.info(f"File listener detected the presence of : {file['name']}.")

    # id_token = authorize_iap()
    # make_iap_request({"file_name": file["name"]}, id_token)
    make_iap_request(url=WEBSERVER_URL, client_id=CLIENT_ID, method="POST")


def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method="GET", **kwargs):
    """Makes a request to an application protected by Identity-Aware Proxy.

    Args:
      url: The Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL to fetch.
      client_id: The client ID used by Identity-Aware Proxy.
      method: The request method to use
              ('GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')
      **kwargs: Any of the parameters defined for the request function:
                https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py
                If no timeout is provided, it is set to 90 by default.

    Returns:
      The page body, or raises an exception if the page couldn't be retrieved.
    """
    # Set the default timeout, if missing
    if "timeout" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["timeout"] = 90

    # Obtain an OpenID Connect (OIDC) token from metadata server or using service account.
    open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), client_id)
    logging.info(f"Retrieved open id connect (bearer) token {open_id_connect_token}")

    # Fetch the Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL, including an authorization header containing "Bearer " followed by a
    # Google-issued OpenID Connect token for the service account.
    resp = requests.request(method, url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {open_id_connect_token}"}, **kwargs)

    if resp.status_code == 403:
        raise Exception("Service account does not have permission to access the IAP-protected application.")
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Bad response from application: {resp.status_code} / {resp.headers} / {resp.text}")
    else:
        logging.info(f"Response status - {resp.status_code}")
        return resp.json
```

This is the code that runs in the GC-functions
I have checked the environment details in **dlkpipelinesv1** and **piplines** respectively, using this code :

```
credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
authed_session = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(
    credentials)

# project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
# location = 'us-central1'
# composer_environment = 'YOUR_COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT_NAME'

environment_url = (
    'https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{}/locations/{}'
    '/environments/{}').format(project_id, location, composer_environment)
composer_response = authed_session.request('GET', environment_url)
environment_data = composer_response.json()
```

and the two are using the same service accounts to run, i.e. the same IAM roles. Although I have noticed the following different details :

In the old environment :

```
"airflowUri": "https://p5<hidden_value>-tp.appspot.com",
    "privateEnvironmentConfig": { "privateClusterConfig": {} },
```

in the new environment:

```
"airflowUri": "https://da<hidden_value>-tp.appspot.com",
    "privateEnvironmentConfig": {
      "privateClusterConfig": {},
      "webServerIpv4CidrBlock": "<hidden_value>",
      "cloudSqlIpv4CidrBlock": "<hidden_value>"
    }
```

The service account that I use to make the post request has the following roles :

```
Cloud Functions Service Agent 
Composer Administrator 
Composer User
Service Account Token Creator 
Service Account User
```

The service account that runs my composer environment has the following roles :

```
BigQuery Admin
Composer Worker
Service Account Token Creator
Storage Object Admin
```

But I am still receiving a `403 - Forbidden` in the `Log Explorer` when the `post` request is made to the airflow API.

EDIT 2020-11-16 :

I've updated to the latest `make_iap_request` code.
I tinkered with the IAP within the security service, but I cannot find the webserver that will accept `HTTP: post` requests from my cloud functions... See the image bellow, anyway I added the service account to the default and CRM IAP resources just in case, but I still get this error :

```
Exception: Service account does not have permission to access the IAP-protected application.
```

The main question is: What IAP is at stake here?? And how do I add my service account as a user of this IAP.

What am I missing?

[image: List of HTTP IAP]

Comment: For folks looking at this in the future, I wanted to add a comment that there is now more robust documentation on triggering dags both here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/triggering-dags
And more detail on using the rest API https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a configuration parameter that causes ALL requests to the API to be denied...

In the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=rbac#api-authentication), it is mentioned that we need to override the following airflow configuration :

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
```

into

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

This detail is really important to know, and it is not mentioned in google's documentation...

Useful links :

1. [Triggering DAGS (workflows) with GCS](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf)
2. [make_iap_request.py repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iap)

Comment: Google may have updated there documents post your issue, but I just ran into the same problem but then re-read the top of the article and ran through the steps to add a airflow configuration overrides parameter: api auth_backend airflow.api.auth.backend.default , then I was able to trigger my composer dag from a file hitting gcs. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf

Comment: Hey! just wanted to confirm that this document has been updated specifically with using the API with GCF, and there is also additional documentation about working with the rest API https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-api

Answer (score 1):

The code throwing the 403 is the way it used to work. There was a breaking change in the middle of 2020.  Instead of using `requests` to make an HTTP call for the token, you should use [Google's OAuth2 library](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html#module-google.oauth2.id_token):

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), client_id)
```

see [this example](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_for_the_default_service_account)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've been reading up about the example you've shown. Please find the EDIT in my post today

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in [Triggering DAGs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) and has worked in my env, please see below my recommendations.

It is a good start that the Componser Environment is up and runnning. Through the process you will only need to upload the new DAG (trigger_response_dag.py) and get the clientID (ends with `.apps.googleusercontent.com`) with either a python script or from the login page the first time you open Airflow UI.

In the Cloud Functions side, I noticed you have a combination of instructions for Node.js and for Python, for example, `USER_AGENT` is only for Node.js. And routine `make_iap_request` is only for python. I hope the following points helps to resolve your problem:

1. Service Account (SA). The Node.js code uses the default service account `${projectId}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` whose default role is Editor, meaning that it has wide access to the GCP services, including Cloud Composer. In python I think the authentication is managed somehow by `client_id` since a token is retrieved with id. Please ensure that the SA has this Editor role and don't forget to assign `serviceAccountTokenCreator` as specified in the guide.
2. I used Node.js 8 runtime and I noticed the user agent you are concerned it should be 'gcf-event-trigger' as it is hard coded; `USER_AGENT = 'gcf-event-trigger'`. In python, it seems not necesary.
3. By default, in the GCS trigger, the [GCS Event Type](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#deploying_and_triggering_the_function) is set to `Archive`, you need to change it to `Finalize/Create`. If set to `Archive`, the trigger won't work when you upload objects, and the DAG won't be started.
4. If you think your cloud function is correctly configured and an error persists, you can find its cause in your cloud function's LOGS tab in the Console. It can give you more details.

Basically, from the guide, I only had to change the following values in Node.js:

```
// The project that holds your function. Replace <YOUR-PROJECT-ID>
const PROJECT_ID = '<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>';
// Navigate to your webserver's login page and get this from the URL
const CLIENT_ID = '<ALPHANUMERIC>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
// This should be part of your webserver's URL in the Env's detail page: {tenant-project-id}.appspot.com. 
const WEBSERVER_ID = 'v90eaaaa11113fp-tp';
// The name of the DAG you wish to trigger. It's DAG's name in the script trigger_response_dag.py you uploaded to your Env.
const DAG_NAME = 'composer_sample_trigger_response_dag';
```

For Python I only changed these parameters:

```
client_id = '<ALPHANUMERIC>.apps.googleusercontent.com'
# This should be part of your webserver's URL:
# {tenant-project-id}.appspot.com
webserver_id = 'v90eaaaa11113fp-tp'
# Change dag_name only if you are not using the example
dag_name = 'composer_sample_trigger_response_dag'
```